# Multiple gravity forms work fine individually, however, if I embed them all in one web page, the html blocks of my gravity forms do not work

Tags: html, wordpress, gravity, gravityforms, divi

Wordpress website built with Divi

Using gravity forms to create conditional logic forms

Having trouble getting multiple forms (6 separate forms with similar conidtional logic pattern and modules) to work together on a website page.

Any suggestions would be helpful, thank you.

Have tried putting the forms in separate blocks, putting them in

Expecting all the forms to work like they do individually, error being displayed for html module blocks used for displaying price on selection and bmi block not appearing. Works fine if it's just one form on the web page.

Comment: Please share your code and steps for [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Thanks